# how to obtain particular observations only that have identical entries in two columns

Tags: r

```
v1=rep(c("a","b","c","d"),each=5)
v2=rep(c(10,12,9,7),each=5)
v3=c("y","y","w","y","y",rep(c("f"),times=5),rep(c("y"),times=4),"w",rep(c("k"),times=5))
v4=c("j","j","w","j","j",rep(c("q"),times=5),rep(c("l"),times=4),"w",rep(c("n"),times=5))
df=data.frame(v1,v2,v3,v4)

   v1 v2 v3 v4
1   a 10  y  j
2   a 10  y  j
3   a 10  w  w
4   a 10  y  j
5   a 10  y  j
6   b 12  f  q
7   b 12  f  q
8   b 12  f  q
9   b 12  f  q
10  b 12  f  q
11  c  9  y  l
12  c  9  y  l
13  c  9  y  l
14  c  9  y  l
15  c  9  w  w
16  d  7  k  n
17  d  7  k  n
18  d  7  k  n
19  d  7  k  n
20  d  7  k  n
>
```

I want to remain with those observations where `v3="w"` and `v4="w"`

```
   v1 v2 v3 v4
1   a 10  y  j
2   a 10  y  j
3   a 10  w  w
4   a 10  y  j
5   a 10  y  j
6   c  9  y  l
7   c  9  y  l
8   c  9  y  l
9   c  9  y  l
10  c  9  w  w
```

how do I go about it

Comment: Your desired output does not fit with the description. Only rows 3 and 10 have `v3=="w"` and `v4=="w"`. Could you edit your question accordingly?

Comment: @thothal I think that "observation" is probably the level in `v1`, just in long and not wide format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please use spaces. Any coding style other than this will work better. About your question, you need to do what @agerom and @thotal suggested, with an extra twist. Collect those `v1` values from the subset and use them to further subset the data.frame.

```
> df[df$v1 %in% unique(df[df$v4 == "w" & df$v3 == "w", ]$v1), ]
   v1 v2 v3 v4
1   a 10  y  j
2   a 10  y  j
3   a 10  w  w
4   a 10  y  j
5   a 10  y  j
11  c  9  y  l
12  c  9  y  l
13  c  9  y  l
14  c  9  y  l
15  c  9  w  w
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select the rows like this:

```
df[df$v3 == "w" & df$v4 == "w", ]
#    v1 v2 v3 v4
# 3   a 10  w  w
# 15  c  9  w  w
```

Comment: I would want all the other rows to remain as well, this just returns me the particular rows

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with `data.table`

```
library("data.table")
dt <- data.table(v1=rep(c("a","b","c","d"), each=5),
                 v2=rep(c(10,12,9,7), each=5),
                 v3=rep(c("y","w","y", "f", "y", "w", "k"), times=c(2,1,2, 5,4,1,5)),
                 v4=rep(c("j","w","j", "q", "l", "w", "n"), times=c(2,1,2, 5,4,1,5))
)
dt[, sel:=any(v3=='w' & v4=='w'), v1][sel==TRUE]
#    v1 v2 v3 v4  sel
# 1:  a 10  y  j TRUE
# 2:  a 10  y  j TRUE
# 3:  a 10  w  w TRUE
# 4:  a 10  y  j TRUE
# 5:  a 10  y  j TRUE
# 6:  c  9  y  l TRUE
# 7:  c  9  y  l TRUE
# 8:  c  9  y  l TRUE
# 9:  c  9  y  l TRUE
# 10:  c  9  w  w TRUE
```

or

```
dt[, sel:=any(v3=='w' & v4=='w'), v1][(sel), .(v1,v2,v3,v4)]
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the following expression:

`df[df$v3=="w" & df$v4=="w",]`

Comment: This gives not the desired output.

Comment: By `v3="w" and v4="w" ` in the question, what exactly is meant?

Comment: This question you shoud put as comment to the original question (not as comment to the answer). There is an accepted answer - so the answer reflects what OP wants.

Comment: Wish I could ( due to reputation I can't) . Thothal asked the same, but I don't get the 'accepted answer' either

Comment: The accepted answer is this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43995698/5414452 (from Roman L.)